# How to align div(data-role="horizontal") Width in Jquery Mobile UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, pug

I want to give 10% for div(class='ui-block-a') and remaining for div(class='ui-block-b').But I am not able to do this??

```
div(data-role="horizontal", data-theme="a", class="ui-bar ui-grid-a",data-overlay-theme="a", data-inline="true")
           div(class='ui-block-a',style="width:10%;)
             div(class='content-primary')
                        ul(data-role='listview')
                            li 
                                a(href="acura.html") Acura
            div(class='ui-block-b', style="width:90%;)
                img(src='/images/sample.jpg', width='500', height='590', style='margin:8px 10px 10px 20px;')
```

[image]

My Output is:

But I want 10% in left side and 90% in right side.But it shares equally.

Comment: aren't you missing closing quotes after your "width:10% and "width:90% statements ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to customize a jQM grid. It is not going to be that simple.

Why don' t you try using the 3rd party jQuery mobile grid plugin. It can be configured much better then original one and it requires only one additional css file:

This plugin is called 960 grid and it can be found here: http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/

Likewise here's what you wanted implemented with this grid:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/jbGx4/

```
    <div data-role="content">
      <fieldset class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_2"><a data-role="button">2</a></div>
        <div class="grid_10"><a data-role="button">10</a></div>  
      </fieldset>          
    </div>
```